# Converting Jackson JSON object references to JSON.Net object references

Tags: java, c#, json, jackson, json.net

I need to be able to deserialize a JSON string produced by Jackson (Java/Spring server) with a C#/JSON.Net client while keeping the object references intact. Jackson uses "@id":1...n for cyclic references, while the reference is denoted by a single integer. JSON.Net uses "$id" and "$ref".

Does anybody know how to convert a JSON string from Jackson to a JSON.Net compatible version?

Comment: Thanks for the contribution.  Would you be so kind as to edit your post so that it is phrased like a question, and then move your solution into an answer post for the question?  That format works better on this site, and will allow others to contribute additional possible solutions.

Comment: @Brian....done, I hope it's ok now;-)

Comment: Thanks!  I made some very minor edits, but looks good otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

Use these settings for JSON.Net:

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
};
```

Use this interceptor to convert the references:

```
public static class JSONInterceptor
{
    public static string sanitizeJSON(string originalJSONFromJava)
    {
        // Get ID right from Jackson to JSON.Net
        string pattern = Regex.Escape(@"""@id"":") + "(\\d+)";
        string replacement = @"""$id"":""$1""";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        string output = rgx.Replace(originalJSONFromJava, replacement);

        // Convert Jackson reference in array
        pattern = @",(\d+)";
        replacement = @",{""$ref"":""$1""}";
        rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        output = rgx.Replace(output, replacement);

        // Convert single Jackson reference to ref
        pattern = Regex.Escape(@"""\\w+"":") + "(\\d+)";
        replacement = @"""$ref"":""$1""";
        rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        output = rgx.Replace(output, replacement);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Call the interceptor and deserialize like this:

```
asset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Asset>(JSONInterceptor.sanitizeJSON(response), settings);
```

The asset class has this layout:

```
public class Asset {

    ....

     // Parent asset
     public Asset parent;
     // Asset agents
     public List<Agents> agent;

     ....
}
```

So, Jackson produces something like:

```
{"@id":1,......."parent":{"@id":15,.....},"agents":[{"@id":6, ......},12,{...}]...}
```

which needs to be converted into something like (JSON.Net):

```
{"$id":"1",...,"$ref":"15",....,"agents":[{...,"$ref":"6",...]}
```

This is what the code above does.

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work: the regular expression is replacing all integers inside lists to reference... but what if integers are just integers? I believe also it will not work if the reference integer is in first position in a list.